# Strange behaviour with PGF/TikZ and Plain TeX output routine

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, plain-tex, output-routine

I noticed a strange behavior when running PGF/tikZ with pdfTeX on my Debian box :
a simple session without tikz:

```
pdftex
**\relax
*Hello World
*\bye
```

do output the page number on the page footer.
On the other hand, loading tikz:

```
pdftex
**\relax
*\input tikz.tex
*Hello World
*\bye`
```

does make the page number on the footer disappear. The page size does not seems to be the cause.

Does any of you have any idea of the cause behind this behaviour?

Comment: You can see the same with just `pgf`: the problem is it's redefinition of `\shipout`. Working on the reasons :-)

Answer (score 15):

The problem is what `pgf` does with `\shipout`. It redefines it to

```
\afterassignment\pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Test\setbox 255=
```

That would be fine if the content of box 255 was set up when plain calls `\shipout`. However, it's not:

```
\plainoutput ->\shipout \vbox {\makeheadline \pagebody \makefootline }\advancepageno    
  \ifnum \outputpenalty >-\@MM \else \dosupereject \fi
```

Notice the `\makefootline` here in particular. What goes wrong is that `\afterassignment` inserts the token `\pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Test` not after the *closing* `}` but after the *opening* `{` bracket, *i.e.* just before `\makeheadline`. 
(This behaviour is documented in the usual places, for example *TeX by Topic*.)

This is all an issue because `pgf` then does some tests on box 255 before firing the `\shipout` primitive as part of the expansion of `\pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Test`. Thus the shipout is taking place before addition of the head/footlines: bad news. (You can see this in `\tracingall` output, where the box appears in completely the wrong place.)

Comment: I've not checked in detail, but I guess you don't see this in LaTeX as it does a series of trials on the output before calling `\shipout`, so has a full box constructed for `pgf` to work with. ConTeXt is likely to be the same.

Answer (score 12):

You can detect that the tokens inserted by `\afterasignment` are in a new `vbox` list rather than the current list and if so, delay them with `\aftergroup`. Two versions, one for classic TeX then after `\bye` a version for `etex`.

```
\input tikz.tex
\catcode`\@=11
\def\shipout{\vskip1sp \afterassignment \zzz \setbox 255= }

\def\zzz{%
\ifdim\lastskip=\z@\expandafter\aftergroup\fi
\zzzz}

\def\zzzz{%
\unskip
\pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Test}

Hello World
\bye


\input tikz.tex
\catcode`\@=11
\def\shipout{\afterassignment \zzz \setbox 255= }

\def\zzz{%
\ifnum\currentgrouptype=4 \expandafter\aftergroup\fi
\pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Test }

Hello World
\bye
```

Answer (score 12):

The problem is, as Joseph Wright detected (beating me for one minute), that PGF makes some wrong assumptions about how the `\shipout` operation is called. If it was, like in LaTeX,

```
\shipout\box255
```

(or some other box register, it doesn't matter), the redefinition of `\shipout` would work. But the redefinition is

```
\def\shipout{\afterassignment\pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Test\setbox255= }
```

which goes wrong when `\shipout\vbox{\makeheadline\pagecontents\makefootline}` is called by the output routine of Plain TeX. Indeed, the TeXbook says

> `\afterassignment<token>`.
>   The `<token>` is saved in a special place; it will be inserted back into the input just after the next assignment command has been performed. An assignment need not follow immediately; if another `\afterassignment` is performed before the next assignment, the second one overrides the first. If the next assignment is a `\setbox`, and if the assigned `<box>` is `\hbox` or `\vbox` or `\vtop`, the `<token>` will be inserted just after the `{` in the box construction, not after the `}`; it will also come just before any tokens inserted by `\everyhbox` or `\everyvbox`.

Thus the test is performed at the wrong time, before `\makeheadline` and `\makefootline` are executed, so that headers and footers will not appear.

PGF makes also another wrong assumptions, that one always calls `\shipout\box<register>` where the box is a `\vbox`. Thus a simple

```
\setbox0=\hbox{A}
\shipout\box0
```

would fail (`Incompatible list can't be unboxed`). Here's a possible fix (using ideas from David Carlisle's answer).

```
\input pgf

\catcode`@=11
\newbox\pgfutil@@Output@Box
\def\shipout{%
  \ifhmode\hskip\else\vskip\fi 1sp 
  \afterassignment\pgfutil@@Delayed@EveryShipout@Test
  \setbox\pgfutil@@Output@Box=}
\def\pgfutil@@Delayed@EveryShipout@Test{%
  \ifdim\lastskip=\z@ % it was \shipout\vbox or \shipout\hbox
    \expandafter\aftergroup
  \fi
  \pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Test}
\def\pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Test{%
  \unskip % remove the skip used as signal
  \ifvoid\pgfutil@@Output@Box
    \expandafter\aftergroup
  \fi
  \pgfutil@EveryShipout@Output}
\def\pgfutil@EveryShipout@Output{%
  \setbox\pgfutil@@Output@Box=\vbox{
    \setbox\z@=\hbox{%
      \pgfutil@abe
      \unhbox\pgfutil@abb
      \pgfutil@abc
      \global\let\pgfutil@abc\pgfutil@empty
    }%
    \wd\z@=\z@\ht\z@=\z@\dp\z@=\z@\box\z@
    \ifhbox\pgfutil@@Output@Box\unhbox\else\unvbox\fi\pgfutil@@Output@Box
  }%
  \pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Org@Shipout\box\pgfutil@@Output@Box
}
\catcode`@=12

%\def\bxxx{\box255}\output={\shipout\bxxx}
%\output={\shipout\relax\box255}

\setbox0=\hbox{A}
\shipout\box0

Hello world
\bye
```

This would probably give wrong results in case of `\shipout\vtop{...}`, which however seems not to be something which is done frequently. A test whether we are in a `\vtop` group, with e-TeX's `\ifnum\currentgrouptype=5` might be made in the `\ifdim\lastskip=\z@` conditional, adjusting things later when

```
\setbox\pgfutil@@Output@Box=\vbox{
```

is executed.

The "naked" shipout operation is performed correctly. Also changing the output routine shows that this *might* work in all normal situations.

A better way could be using the `atbegshi` package by Heiko Oberdiek, without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Note that the patch doesn't seem to be needed with PGF version 3.0.0