# headlines are not shown with tikz input (plain TeX)

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, plain-tex, output-routine

I'm usign plain TeX with custom headlines. If I load Tikz packages with

```
 \input tikz
```

then headlines are blank. The following are my headlines (some commands don't belong to plain TeX, but I think that those don't create the output bug)

```
    \headline={%
    \ifodd\pageno\leftheadline\else\rightheadline\fi}  

    \def\rightheadline{%
    \ifInizioCapitolo{\nopagenumbers\global\InizioCapitolofalse}%
    \else
    \ifnum\chapnum>0{%
            \folio\qquad{}{\uppercase{\the\chapnum.\ \chaptertitle}}\hfill\copyright}
        \else%
            {\folio\qquad{}\uppercase{\chaptertitle}\hfill\copyright}
        \fi%
    \fi}

    \def\leftheadline{%
    \ifInizioCapitolo{\nopagenumbers\global\InizioCapitolofalse}%
    \else
            \ifnum\chapnum>0{%
            \copyright\hfill{\uppercase{\the\chapnum.\ \chaptertitle}}\qquad\folio}
            \else%
            {\copyright\hfill{\uppercase{\chaptertitle}}\qquad{}\folio} 
            \fi%
    \fi}
```

I'm already using tikz in LaTeX documents but I would use it in plain ones too. So, I can fix this bug?

Comment: Here's an analysis of the problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88782/strange-behaviour-with-pgf-tikz-and-plain-tex-output-routine The fix I proposed in my answer seems to work.