# Why importing pgfplots changes behavior of \vfill?

Tags: pgfplots, xetex, vertical-alignment, plain-tex

When I import `pgfplots`, it affects behavior of `\vfill`.

The following code works as expected:

```
This should be at the top of the page.
\vfill
This should be at the bottom of the page.
\eject
\end
```

whereas with the following, both lines go at the top of the page:

```
\input pgfplots.tex
This should be at the top of the page.
\vfill
This should be at the bottom of the page but isn't.
\eject
\end
```

Why is that? How can I mitigate this effect, so that the latter code work as expected?

(I use plain XeTeX)

Comment: I have a feeling this is [Strange behaviour with PGF/TikZ and Plain TeX output routine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88782/strange-behaviour-with-pgf-tikz-and-plain-tex-output-routine): you get the same in pdfTeX just loading `pgf.tex`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format

Comment: The problem is the same as in [Strange behaviour with PGF/TikZ and Plain TeX output routine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88782/) and the fix I proposed there (to be typed after `\input pgfplots`) works.

Comment: @egreg, thank you very much, it solved the problem indeed.

Comment: @JosephWright thank you for pointing the answer