# plain TeX error. Undefined control sequence. \pgfutil@

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, tex-core

I'm trying to compile the fix mentioned by egreg in this thread: [Strange behaviour with PGF/TikZ and Plain TeX output routine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88782/strange-behaviour-with-pgf-tikz-and-plain-tex-output-routine)

Here's the code:

```
\input pgf

\catcode`@=11
\newbox\pgfutil@@Output@Box
\def\shipout{%
  \ifhmode\hskip\else\vskip\fi 1sp 
  \afterassignment\pgfutil@@Delayed@EveryShipout@Test
  \setbox\pgfutil@@Output@Box=}
\def\pgfutil@@Delayed@EveryShipout@Test{%
  \ifdim\lastskip=\z@ % it was \shipout\vbox or \shipout\hbox
    \expandafter\aftergroup
  \fi
  \pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Test}
\def\pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Test{%
  \unskip % remove the skip used as signal
  \ifvoid\pgfutil@@Output@Box
    \expandafter\aftergroup
  \fi
  \pgfutil@EveryShipout@Output}
\def\pgfutil@EveryShipout@Output{%
  \setbox\pgfutil@@Output@Box=\vbox{
    \setbox\z@=\hbox{%
      \pgfutil@abe
      \unhbox\pgfutil@abb
      \pgfutil@abc
      \global\let\pgfutil@abc\pgfutil@empty
    }%
    \wd\z@=\z@\ht\z@=\z@\dp\z@=\z@\box\z@
    \ifhbox\pgfutil@@Output@Box\unhbox\else\unvbox\fi\pgfutil@@Output@Box
  }%
  \pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Org@Shipout\box\pgfutil@@Output@Box
}
\catcode`@=12

%\def\bxxx{\box255}\output={\shipout\bxxx}
%\output={\shipout\relax\box255}

\setbox0=\hbox{A}
\shipout\box0

Hello world
\bye
```

I get this error message every time I try:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfutil@EveryShipout@Output ...ipout@Org@Shipout 
                                                  \box \pgfutil@@Output@Box 
\plainoutput ...headline \pagebody \makefootline }
                                                  \advancepageno \ifnum \out...
<output> {\plainoutput 
              }
<to be read again> 
\pgfutil@origend 
l.42    \bye

? 
! Output loop---25 consecutive dead cycles.
<to be read again> 
\pgfutil@origend 
l.42    \bye
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think the code is necessary with PGF 3.0.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple file

```
\input pgf

\show\shipout
```

produces different results when compiled using TeX Live 2012, with PGF version 2.10, or under TeX Live 2014, with PGF version 3.0.0

### Version 2.1.0

```
> \shipout=macro:
->\afterassignment \pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Test \setbox 255= .
```

### Version 3.0.0

```
> \shipout=macro:
->\edef \AtBegShi@GroupLevel {\number \currentgrouplevel }\afterassignment \AtBegShi@Test \setbox \AtBeginShipoutBox =.
```

The conclusion we can draw from this code is that the main error in PGF 2.10, which was doing `\setbox255=...` has been fixed. In my experiment, the example file you show (purged from the added code)

```
\input pgf

\setbox0=\hbox{A}
\shipout\box0

Hello world
\bye
```

compiles flawlessly and produces the expected result.

Answer (score 5):

The code from @egreg's answer supposes that there is

```
\let\pgfutil@@EveryShipout@Org@Shipout=\shipout
```

in the macros of `pgf.tex`. The error message shown in your post says that the line above is not processed. Maybe, a new or old version of PGF uses another control sequence names or does something different and the @egreg's code is incompatible with this because the line above is missing in the code. But this line cannot be in the path itself from principal reason: we don't know if the `\shipout` is still primitive or not. The line above works only if `\shipout` is primitive.

Recommendation: don't use this path if exactly don't know that the version of PGF is the same as version discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88782/strange-behaviour-with-pgf-tikz-and-plain-tex-output-routine). I don't know the version evolution of PGF so I cannot say more.